# Como pesquisar arquivos recursivamente dentro de uma pasta?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação, e preciso retornar os caminhos de arquivos que tenham mesmo nome e mesma extensão de dentro de uma pasta especifica, para atribuir um versão há eles, mas não conheço nenhum método para ter como base. 
Basicamente, eu teria que buscar na pasta base do projeto os arquivos de nome Assemblyinfo.cs, e jogar esses caminhos para dentro de um array, mas não sei como fazer a consulta.
Resolvida por : **dcastro**

```
  var files = Directory.GetFiles("C://caminho_de_amostra", "AssemblyInfo.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
//Pesquisa no caminho atribuido o nome "Assemblyinfo.cs"
            for (int h = 0; h < files.Length; h++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(files[h]);// Apenas para ter um texto mostrando qual arquivo foi modificado
                File.WriteAllLines(files[h], File.ReadAllLines(files[h]).Select(s => !s.Trim().StartsWith("[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion(") ? s : string.Join(".", s.Trim(']').Trim(')').Trim('"').Split('.').Select((n, i) => i != 3 ? n : !int.TryParse(n, out num) ? n : (anum))) + "\")]"));
            }// Modifica a versão arquivo por arquivo.
```

Comment: Bem, o algoritmo envolve fazer uma pesquisa recursiva de ficheiros dentro de uma pasta, depois comparar os nomes, etc... Qual o passo em que tens duvidas? A pergunta precisa de ser mais especifica.

Comment: Bem, tenho duvida no passo de pesquisa.

Comment: Editei o titulo da pergunta para reflectir melhor a duvida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para pesquisar resurviamente todos os ficheiros dentro de um directorio (e sub-directorios), usa [`Directory.GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx) com a opcao `SearchOptions.AllDirectories`.

```
 var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:/folder", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Para pesquisar por apenas ficheiros com o nome `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
 var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:/folder", "AssemblyInfo.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Tambem podes usar [`EnumerateFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571(v=vs.110).aspx) em vez de `GetFiles` para fazer a pesquisa de modo *lazy*. Assim, os ficheiros sao encontrados a' medida que vao sendo precisos. `EnumerateFiles` retorna `IEnumerable<string>` em vez de `string[]`.

Comment: Obrigado. Resolveu o meu problema.